# Excessive amount of "select count(*)" from Zabbix to the MySQL database

Tags: linux, mysql

I have some problems with my Zabbix Server as it is constantly slow. So I enabled the slow query highlighting in syslog in the Zabbix Server config. Why is it constantly doing select count(*) on these tables? (They are HUGE!). Is there a way to circumvent this behaviour of Zabbix?

```
zabbix_server[13501]: slow query: 129.014900 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13501]: slow query: 178.554334 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13501]: slow query: 25.102330 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13505]: slow query: 754.050522 sec, "select count(*) from history"
zabbix_server[13509]: slow query: 180.450058 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13512]: slow query: 122.668146 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13512]: slow query: 172.661542 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13512]: slow query: 31.664581 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13515]: slow query: 210.105187 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13516]: slow query: 27.483541 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13516]: slow query: 93.289657 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13518]: slow query: 102.836916 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13522]: slow query: 130.317530 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13524]: slow query: 29.246892 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13524]: slow query: 31.702153 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13525]: slow query: 34.628497 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13529]: slow query: 106.031498 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13529]: slow query: 160.210204 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13532]: slow query: 171.634335 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13534]: slow query: 75.451523 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13536]: slow query: 132.403058 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13536]: slow query: 25.296489 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13539]: slow query: 1138.864792 sec, "select count(*) from history"
zabbix_server[13542]: slow query: 1001.632530 sec, "select count(*) from history"
zabbix_server[13542]: slow query: 619.885084 sec, "select count(*) from history"
zabbix_server[13549]: slow query: 22.035550 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13550]: slow query: 25.015439 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13550]: slow query: 51.222695 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13552]: slow query: 106.272890 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13552]: slow query: 57.781271 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13558]: slow query: 195.948071 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13558]: slow query: 35.949829 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13561]: slow query: 27.496382 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13561]: slow query: 59.612290 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13562]: slow query: 266.540841 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13562]: slow query: 815.081735 sec, "select count(*) from history"
zabbix_server[13564]: slow query: 739.742027 sec, "select count(*) from history"
zabbix_server[13565]: slow query: 25.792558 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13565]: slow query: 662.055581 sec, "select count(*) from history"
zabbix_server[13566]: slow query: 166.917401 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13569]: slow query: 133.917164 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13569]: slow query: 375.701664 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13576]: slow query: 30.821537 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13576]: slow query: 323.511372 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13576]: slow query: 739.250067 sec, "select count(*) from history"
zabbix_server[13576]: slow query: 98.566847 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13577]: slow query: 118.234232 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13577]: slow query: 29.402386 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13582]: slow query: 1633.032010 sec, "select count(*) from history"
zabbix_server[13584]: slow query: 39.793458 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13587]: slow query: 27.135422 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13595]: slow query: 35.727087 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13600]: slow query: 134.139426 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13601]: slow query: 27.672915 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13602]: slow query: 273.831060 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13607]: slow query: 60.470353 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13610]: slow query: 135.439930 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13610]: slow query: 179.540891 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13613]: slow query: 117.768700 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13613]: slow query: 165.944011 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13613]: slow query: 44.678274 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13615]: slow query: 33.423619 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13617]: slow query: 19.533471 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13617]: slow query: 411.857382 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13621]: slow query: 118.574077 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
zabbix_server[13622]: slow query: 21.323747 sec, "select count(*) from history_str"
zabbix_server[13625]: slow query: 156.002532 sec, "select count(*) from trends"
```

**Edit:** Since I couldn't solve the problems (and no one couldn't either) I have dumped the tables and purged the data inside them. Zabbix is (of course) running much faster right now.

Answer (score 0):

Do these tables have any index fields (e,g, a primary key)?  if not, adding an index should speed things up.

Another option is to tune Mysql to make better use of RAM.  And maybe install more RAM in the server - mysql can really fly when you give it a lot of memory, but slows down when insufficient RAM means it doesn't get the opportunity to cache answers to frequent queries, or keep tables and/or indexes entirely in memory.

Finally, a caching SQL proxy between Zabbix and Mysql may help (at the price of occasionally getting stale data from the cache) - it's been years since I used one so can't recommend any specific software.  Try googling for `mysql proxy cache`.

Comment: All these tables have indexes. The database is about 62 GB big, so completely keeping this monster in RAM would be a pricy option. The thing is that zabbix used to work okay but by the time it became slower and slower. The best option would be to disable those senseless select counts but I can't find where.

Comment: 1. can you archive old data into another mysql?  2, how do you know the count queries are 'senseless'?   3. have you tried grepping the zabbix source for the query: `grep -ir 'select count(\*)' /path/to/zabbix`

Comment: Actually I have deleted old data from the tables a couple months ago but that also didn't help. I need the last 365 days of data stored in the DB. One of the first things I learned about performant MySQL coding was to avoid select count(*) on huge tables. I can't see the point in these queries.